# Prevent Qt5 app from crashing due to plugins

Tags: plugins, segmentation-fault, qt5, qtplugin

I'm building a Qt5 app that makes use of Qt's plugin framework. While testing the app, I noticed that if there is s some problem with the plugin causing it to crash, it takes down the app as well. Is there a way to insulate the app from these crashes caused by the plugin?

I have noticed that plasmashell also uses plugins and somehow when these plugins crash (ex: plasma-nm or power management) it does not crash plasmashell.

Either I'm missing something, or plasmashell is doing something to handle those crashes.

Comment: Executing them as a separate process is the first thing, which comes to my mind.

Comment: @scopchanov My plugin is a shows a Gui Widget in the main app. So you mean to suggest that I should build the GUI as a plugin that can be shown, and the launch a separate process to to update the data in the widget through sockets? Can you think of any drawbacks of doing this?